# Spring Load Balancer, RestTemplate, and Microservices issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, load-balancing, resttemplate

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429963/spring-resttemplate-and-getforobject-for-microservices-issues), I configured

(1) a Eureka Server,

(2) a toll rate service which is a client of (1),

(3) a toll rate dashboard which read data from (2).

It went well until I made some changes using @LoadBalanced (maybe it is not exactly due to load balancer, but I'll post related code chunks below)

In bootstrap.properties in (2), the common endpoint name is

```
spring.application.name = demo-tollrate-service
```

In DashboardController.java in (3), as you can see the HTTP address is changed to above application name

```
// import some libraries

@Controller
public class DashboardController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
    public String GetTollRate(@RequestParam int stationId, Model m) {
        
        TollRate tr = restTemplate.getForObject("http://demo-tollrate-service/tollrate/" + stationId, TollRate.class);
        
        m.addAttribute("rate", tr.getCurrentRate());
        
        return "dashboard";
    }
    
}
```

The pom.xml is roughly the same in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429963/spring-resttemplate-and-getforobject-for-microservices-issues)

When running this app, I got the below errors.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  dashboardController (field private org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate com.example.demo.DashboardController.restTemplate)
└──<-──┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

Can anyone please help me here? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running with —debug?

Comment: it gives the same error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a circular dependency, the DashboardController depends on the RestTemplate, but the RestTemplate is defined inside the DashboardController.

The Java version does not make any difference, but maybe the Spring version. The new Spring version is not allowing circular references by default. You can change that adding a property in the application.properties file, here you can find more details:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default

But I recommend a refactor, there is no good reason to define the RestTemplate inside the controller, it is much better to do it in a @Configuration class.

Answer (score 2):

Spring 101: You can’t define beans in a controller class. Move `RestRemplate` definition to a `@Configuration` class or to your application main class.

Comment: thanks for reply, but this is actually based on instructor's code, and it worked for the instructor (he used Java 8 but I use Java 11, will it make a difference?)